# How to sum for each pvkey depending on date and has to be >=250

Tags: sql, addition

I need to add up the amount for every `pvkey` and only those pvkeys where is `total_amount >= 250` should be listed and they're depending on a certain year/date.

```
select finance.pvkey,sum(amount) from finance 
inner join contact
on contact.pvkey = finance.pvkey
where rectype='TOP_MAJDON'or rectype='MAJ_DON' or rectype='MEMBER'or rectype='MAJORDON'
and transdate between '2015-01-01' and '2015-12-31' and amount >=250
group by finance.pvkey
```

I'm getting results but some of them are incorrect, some of them are less then 250 and they are not inside certain date (between '2015-01-01' and '2015-12-31').

Comment: Hi @garincha03 one thing : make sure that your transdate has the following `CONVERT(char(10), transdate,126) BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-12-31'` in case you are using sqlserver. You need to mention what type of data engine you are using

Answer (score 1):

When using `OR` together with `AND` it is necessary to have parenthesis
Like so:

```
(rectype='TOP_MAJDON'or rectype='MAJ_DON' or rectype='MEMBER'or rectype='MAJORDON')
and transdate between '2015-01-01' and '2015-12-31' and amount >=250
```

otherwize you will not get what you want

Answer (score 1):

Use having for aggregation function filter

```
 select finance.pvkey,sum(amount) from finance 
 inner join contact
 on contact.pvkey = finance.pvkey
 where rectype='TOP_MAJDON'or rectype='MAJ_DON' or rectype='MEMBER'or   rectype='MAJORDON'
 and transdate between '2015-01-01' and '2015-12-31' 
 group by finance.pvkey 
 having amount >=250
```

Comment: Wrong order... GROUP BY goes before HAVING.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix your `where` clause and add a `having` clause.  I would recommend using `in` for the `where`:

```
select f.pvkey, sum(amount)
from finance f inner join
     contact c
     on c.pvkey = f.pvkey
where rectype in ('TOP_MAJDON', 'MAJ_DON', 'MEMBER', 'MAJORDON') and
      transdate between '2015-01-01' and '2015-12-31'
group by f.pvkey 
having sum(amount) >= 250;
```

Note:  I am assuming that "total_amount" in the question refers to `sum(amount)`.  If it actually refers to `amount` then keep the comparison in the `where` clause.

I should add:  You seem confused about `and` and `or` in conditions.  Until you are comfortable with such logic, I recommend that you use parentheses around your conditional expressions.